# Laravel comment system

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I'm currently developing a comment function in Laravel 5. I want to display instantly the comment the user just post. So how can I achieve that? I have tried to use `load()` method in AJAX, but it still doesn't work.

Here is the controller to insert a comment:

```
public function newComment(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $date_format = date('Y-m-d');
        $comment=new Comment();
        $comment->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
        $comment->introduce=$request->introduce;
        $comment->completed_day=$request->completed_day;
        $comment->allowance=str_replace( ',', '', $request->allowance);
        $comment->post_at=$date_format;
        $comment->job_id=$request->job_id;
        $comment->save();

        return response()->json(array('mess'=>'Success'));
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        return response()->json(array('err'=>'Error'));
    }
}
```

Here is the view and `{{$jobReply -> user -> full_name }}` im using ORM to get user name

```
<div class="panel-body"  id="job_comment_post" style="text-align:left">
    <table class="table table-hover"> 
        <thead> 
            <tr> 
                <th>Freelancer name</th> 
                <th>Introduce</th> 
                <th>Completed day</th> 
                <th>Allowance</th> 
            </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
            @foreach($job_comment as $jobReply)
                <tr> 
                    <td>{{$jobReply -> user -> full_name }}</td> 
                    <td>{{$jobReply -> introduce}}</td>
                    <td>{{$jobReply -> completed_day}}</td>
                    <td>{{number_format($jobReply -> allowance)}}</td>
                </tr> 
            @endforeach()
        </tbody> 
    </table>

    <div class="details_pagi">
        {!! $job_comment->render() !!}
    </div>                      
</div>
```

This is AJAX to insert comment:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnInsertComment').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var data=$("#commentForm").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/postComment',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success:function(data) {
                    alert(data.mess);
                    //job_comment_post is the div i want to load new comment
                    $("#job_comment_post").load();
                    $("#commentForm")[0].reset();
                },
                error:function(data) {
                    alert(data.err);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$("#job_comment_post").append(yourhtml);` Just grab the html by fetching values from your inputs with `$("#input").val()`.

Comment: Hi @Matt the thing i struggle with is {{$jobReply -> user -> full_name }} because i'm use orm i'm not type that in the view so how can i get that

Comment: Cleaned up formatting and grammar.